# Show Model name in a template

Tags: django, templates

In all the views I make, a usually declare something like "model = Student", or any other model. What I want to make is to show

## Insert Student

in the template. Is there an easy way to doing that without passing a new variable in the context?

I've seen some answers here, but all of them had to change the view =/

Actually what I want to show is the:
    class Meta:
        **verbose_name** = _(u"Student")

In the model I passed through the view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Model name of objects in django templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571649/model-name-of-objects-in-django-templates)

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432142/django-template-display-model-verbose-names-objects

Answer (score 0):

Class name in Python is stored in `__class__.__name__` attribute of any object. By default Django won't permit you to use attributes starting with `__` (double underscore) in templates, as it indicates private attribute.

The simply solution is to write a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

```
@register.filter
def classname(obj):
    return obj.__class__.__name__
```

Then use it in your template (remember to `{% load libraryname %}` in your template first):

```
{{ obj|classname }} # Will print the class name of obj
```

Comment: I see, but the problem here is that I don't have an object yet. I am in an empty list view, and a need a link to Insert Student. Your solution works fine with an object.

All I have is a model = Student context related to Student that I passed in the view...

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achive.