# field's verbose_name in templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Suppose I have a model:

```
from django.db import models

class Test(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'custom name')
```

How do I get my model's field's verbose name in templates? The following doesn't work:

`{{ test_instance.name.verbose_name }}`

I would very much appreciate the solution, something on lines as we do when using forms, using label attribute in template:

```
{{ form_field.label }}
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7432142/630877

Comment: Please follow the post hope it works in your case.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432142/django-template-display-model-verbose-names-objects

Comment: I have create a custom template tag for you. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use following python code for this

```
Test._meta.get_field("name").verbose_name.title()
```

If you want to use this in template then it will be best to register template tag for this. Create a `templatetags` folder inside your app containing two files (`__init__.py` and `verbose_names.py`).Put following code in `verbose_names.py`:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_verbose_field_name(instance, field_name):
    """
    Returns verbose_name for a field.
    """
    return instance._meta.get_field(field_name).verbose_name.title()
```

Now you can use this template tag in your template after loading the library like this:

```
{% load verbose_names %}
{% get_verbose_field_name test_instance "name" %}
```

You can read about [`Custom template tags`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) in official django documentation.

Comment: Just a small warning: if you use `.title()` the string won't be properly translated unless it just so happens you've already set that string ("Name") for translation someplace else. To avoid this, skip `title()` and worry about styling in css (not to mention the use of `title()` is not correct for all languages)

Answer (score 9):

The method in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14498938/353550) is awesome!

And maybe you'll like this if you want to generate a field list.

Adding an iterable to the class Test makes it convenient to list fields' verbose name and value.

**Model**

```
class Test(models.Model):
...
def __iter__(self):
    for field in self._meta.fields:
        yield (field.verbose_name, field.value_to_string(self))
```

**Template**

```
{% for field, val in test_instance %}
<div>
    <label>{{ field }}:</label>
    <p>{{ val }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That’s a nice idea!  It could be a method named `list_fields` though, which would be a little more explicit (`for field, value in instance.list_fields`) and less confusing (what does it mean to iterate over a XyzModel instance?)

Answer (score 1):

based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14498938 .in Django Model i added

```
class Meta:
  app_name = 'myapp'
```

in listview i have

```
from django.core import serializers
context['data'] = serializers.serialize( "python", self.get_queryset() )
```

inside mylist.html i have

```
{% for field, value in data.0.fields.items %}
<th style="text-align:center;">{% get_verbose_field_name data.0.model field %}</th>
{% endfor %}
```

in filter:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
from .models import Mymodel
@register.simple_tag
def get_verbose_field_name(instance, field_name):
  """
  Returns verbose_name for a field.
  """
  myinstance = eval(instance.split('.')[1].title())
  return myinstance._meta.get_field(field_name).verbose_name.title()
```

instance in the abbove filter for the specific example is myapp.mymodel i evalute instance into model object and the i return field verbose name

it works in django 1.9

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late for an answer but I had the same issue until I realised that I caused the problem by overriding the fields in the form.py (self.fields['fieldname'] = ..). If you do that you also need to set a label otherwise it uses a label derived from the fieldname.

Hope this quick reply makes sense.