# Prevent capitalization in model field's verbose_name

Tags: django

I use the following template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_verbose_field_name(instance, field_name):
    """
    Returns verbose_name for a field.
    """
    return instance._meta.get_field(field_name).verbose_name.title()
```

Assume I have defined a model field `lorem_ipsum` with  the field's `verbose_name="FOO bar"`.

Then, when I run `{% get_verbose_field_name object "lorem_ipsum" %}` in the template in a table's `<th>` element, I receive "Foo Bar".

However, I want to keep the verbose name exactly how I defined it—in this example as "FOO bar". **How can one disable auto-capitalization of verbose names**?

Comment: Where is this template tag from? I assume it isn't in your code base or you would just modify it, right?

Comment: It is from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14498938/7522891

Comment: Then you should modify the code to keep the verbose name the way you want rather than change it to title case.

Comment: I am not that familiar with string handling in Python yet so I didn't spot that `.title()` was the issue. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: I strongly encourage you to understand what code is doing when you copy/paste it from stack overflow. You can always add `print()` statements to explore what is going on. For a long line like `instance._meta.get_field(field_name).verbose_name.title()`, print out each piece. For example `print(instance)`, `print(instance._meta)`, etc. Good luck with your programming journey!

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree—at the time of asking this question, I had been coding for 14 hours straight and had become all square-eyed. So I wasn't in my trying-things-out mindset, but I'll definitely use your suggestion going forward!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use both of the below methods for this purpose:

```py
@register.simple_tag
def get_verbose_field_name(instance, field_name):
    """
    Returns verbose_name for a field.
    """
    return instance._meta.get_field(field_name).verbose_name
```

or

```py
@register.simple_tag
def get_verbose_field_name(instance, field_name):
    """
    Returns verbose_name for a field.
    """
    return instance._meta.get_field_by_name(field_name).verbose_name
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the call to `title()`:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_verbose_field_name(instance, field_name):
    """
    Returns verbose_name for a field.
    """
    return instance._meta.get_field(field_name).verbose_name
```